# How to make nested lists work properly in dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create nested Lists but the output I got is not what I have expected.

```
void main() {
  List<int> row = List();
  List<List<int>> rows = List();

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {

    row.add(i+1);
    row.add(i+2);
    row.add(i+3);
    rows.add(row);
    row.clear();
  }

  print(rows);
}
```

The output I got :

```
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

The output I was Expecting:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[5,6,7]]
```

What changes can I should make run this code properly?

Comment: On each iteration, you add a reference to the same `List` instance (`row`).  Since you ultimately clear that instance, you end up with a `List` of empty `List`s.  You want to add separate `List` instances instead (e.g. `rows.add([...row])` or `rows.add(List<int>.of(row))`.)

Answer (score 2):

As @shubham answer says, you should create the List inside the for loop because you're referencing the same object, so when you're clearing at the end of the for that also cleanse all the objects inside

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

```
void main() {
  List<List<int>> rows = List();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    List<int> row = List();
    row.add(i + 1);
    row.add(i + 2);
    row.add(i + 3);
    rows.add(row);
  }
  print(rows); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the @Shubham's code is outdated. Try using this:

```dart
void main() {
  List<List<int>> rows = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    List<int> row = [];
    row.add(i + 1);
    row.add(i + 2);
    row.add(i + 3);
    rows.add(row);
  }
  print(rows); 
}
```